# Magento Setting Up Cron “Error during saving of crontab: sh: line 6: crontab: command not found”

Tags: magento2.3, cron, crontab, magento-cron

I don't have much knowledge in Magento, but I'm spending a lot of time trying to set up crontab. I tried to follow the steps available on the Magento website, but early on when I try to run the command
`bin/magento cron: install --force` 
I already come across an error that I can't solve. I use Professional Cloud Server from Hostinger. Can someone help me?

[image: As you can see.]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the crontab is configured

```
crontab -l
```

A sample follows:

```
#~ MAGENTO START
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v Ran jobs by schedule >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
#~ MAGENTO END
```

**Refer devDoc** [Cron config](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)

**Please check and let me know. Happy to contribute**

Comment: When I try this command, it returns the value `no crontab for XXXX`

Answer (score 0):

There is either no crontab command for your environment or you couldn't access it.

Please type in the terminal:

```
which crontab
```

which should return something like below:

```
~ $ which crontab
/usr/bin/crontab
```

Edit:

Since your system return that statement for alias, alias is a way to link a command/function to execute another command/function.

add this into your ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile or ~/.bashprofile depends on your environement

```
alias crontab='__crontab'
```

see https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias

Comment: I tried using this command and got this answer.

`alias crontab='__crontab'`  

Any Idea?